Why can GitHub Actions check out the repository when I specify `contents: none` permission?
Consider the code:
on:
  workflow_dispatch:


permissions:
  contents: none

jobs:
  job-1:
    name: Job 1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 5
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

It succeeds, although permissions.contents: none remove the permission from secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN.

Presumably your repo is public, so no permissions are required to clone it. In a private repo that example will fail.

Thank you. Yes, the repo is public. I will test it out with a private repo. Could you link to the docs saying that permissions are not needed for public repos?
